# Hyperlink TO specific shape in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I see the option for creating a hyperlink from a shape on one slide to a different slide in the presentation. I don't, however, see a way to hyperlink from a shape on one slide to a specific shape on the same/another slide. I can only link from a shape to the full slide, which isn't helpful. How can I link to a specific shape?

[image: Exemple of expected behavior]

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint doesn't support that because when you're presenting your slides, the entire slide is shown on the screen, so even if you are able to hyperlink another shape in the same slide, it wouldn't make a difference because you'll be in the same slide.

But if you're talking about a feature like Prezi, where you can zoom in to particular shape to reveal further information, that feature in PowerPoint is called Zoom. You can find more about it here:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T3XX7KWbLU
2. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-zoom-for-powerpoint-to-bring-your-presentation-to-life-9d6c58cd-2125-4d29-86b1-0097c7dc47d7